# how to send data to backend in key value structure using json

Tags: javascript, json

```
var idd ;
var subjects        =   [];
var ctr             =   0;

var teacher         =   $('#selectTeacher option:selected').text();

for(var j = 0 ; j < lstClasses.length ; j++)
{  
    var sub         =   {};
    var key         =   lstClasses[j];

    for(var i = 0 ; i < lstSubjects.length ; i++)
    {
        var id      =   lstClasses[j] + lstSubjects[i];
        var cls     =   $('#'+id).attr('class');

        if(cls.indexOf('tickimage') >= 0)   
        {   
            if(ctr  ==  0)
            {
                var val     =   [];
            }

            ctr     =   ctr +   1;
            idd     =   id.replace(lstClasses[j], "");

            val.push(idd);
            /* console.log(val); */

            sub[key]    =   val; 
        }
        /* console.log(sub); */
        subjects.push(sub);
    }
  }
```

the data that i'm sending is not going to backend properly in the json format.i just want to send particular class data and its subjects but when sending the data its not going properly

Comment: Maybe attach your data, it's hard to guess how data looks like just looking into source code that process this data.

Comment: Can you elaborate your question with sample data and how u r passing to backend. Because couldnt figure out how class data and subject data will look like